# facing issue in Consumable and Auto renewable IAP in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I’m working on application which contains two types of IAP.

**1. Consumable IAP**

**2. Auto renewable IAP**

Consumable IAP is working fine. But I confused in Auto renewable IAP.

1. Should I need to store validation receipt in db?
2. How I check is user cancelled Subscription?
3. If user Subscribed using Auto renewable IAP and then after user use Consumable IAP to purchase different Item. In this case which receipt is I need to send for receipt validation for Auto renewable IAP? Latest receipt generated using Consumable IAP or old one which is generated using Auto renewable IAP?
4. I’m also confused in transaction id and original transaction id.

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For auto-renewable subscriptions, the best way is to store the receipt file in your database like you said. From there, you can periodically refresh it with the Apple `/verifyReceipt` endpoint to get the latest subscription status for a user.

This video is useful as a high level guide for setting up a server to handle this: [How to Build a Great iOS In-app Purchase Subscription Server](https://www.revenuecat.com/2019/07/16/altconf-subscriptions-are-hard)

The latest receipt file will contain the entire purchase history for a user, so this is what you should be updating and refreshing in your database.

For auto-renewable subscriptions, the transaction id is a unique identifier for the purchase or renewal. The original transaction id will be the same for all renewals, and can be used to see how many renewals an individual user had.

Comment: Thank You @enc_life. one more question. should we need to refresh receipt on update or on an install of application? If Yes how I refresh receipt?

Comment: Thank You @enc_life. I got it after watching the video.